# What's the unit of buffers_checkpoint in pg_stat_bgwriter table?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL-9.1.6 and trying to build monitoring application for postgreSQL server.

I'm planning to select PHYSICAL and LOGICAL I/O stat from `pg_stat_*` information tables.

According to [MANUAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html) unit of fields in `PG_STAT_DATABASE` is **BLOCK** which means size of **8KB**.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_database where datname='postgres';    
-[ RECORD 3 ]-+------------------------------
datid         | 12780
datname       | postgres
numbackends   | 2
xact_commit   | 974
xact_rollback | 57
blks_read     | 210769
blks_hit      | 18664177
tup_returned  | 16074339
tup_fetched   | 35121
tup_inserted  | 18182015
tup_updated   | 572
tup_deleted   | 3075
conflicts     | 0
```

I could figure out size of `PHYSICAL READ` usging `blks_read` * 8KB.
However, there is no comments on the unit of stats in `PG_STAT_BGWRITER`.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_bgwriter;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------+------------------------------
checkpoints_timed     | 276
checkpoints_req       | 8
buffers_checkpoint    | 94956
buffers_clean         | 0
maxwritten_clean      | 0
buffers_backend       | 82618
buffers_backend_fsync | 0
buffers_alloc         | 174760
stats_reset           | 2013-07-15 22:27:05.503125+09
```

How can I calculate the size of `PHYSICAL WRITE` through the `buffers_checkpoint`?

Any advice wold be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the de facto performance handbook "Postgresql 9.0 High Performance" by Greg Smith, in the chapter on Database Activity and Statistics:

- What percentage of the time are checkpoints being requested based on activity instead of time passing?
- How much data does the average checkpoint write?
- What percentage of the data being written out happens from checkpoints and backends, respectively?

> ```
> SELECT
>     (100 * checkpoints_req) /
>         (checkpoints_timed + checkpoints_req) AS checkpoints_req_pct,
>     pg_size_pretty(buffers_checkpoint * block_size /
>          (checkpoints_timed + checkpoints_req)) AS avg_checkpoint_write,
>     pg_size_pretty(block_size *
>         (buffers_checkpoint + buffers_clean + buffers_backend)) AS total_written,
>     100 * buffers_checkpoint /
>         (buffers_checkpoint + buffers_clean + buffers_backend) AS checkpoint_write_pct,
>     100 * buffers_backend /
>         (buffers_checkpoint + buffers_clean + buffers_backend) AS backend_write_pct,
>     *
> FROM pg_stat_bgwriter,
> (SELECT cast(current_setting('block_size') AS integer) AS block_size) bs;
> ```